# Iterating through tuples of varying sizes in a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

This is an exercise to find the smallest number out of three options in a tuple. If the tuple doesn’t have exactly three option, then it should be skipped.

Why doesn’t the code below work. I thought that len() return an integer and would be comparable to an integer of 3, starting the second for loop to solve the problem.
Thanks for any help you can give in advance,

xoxo

```
data = [
    (3),
    (7, 3, 5),
    (15, 20, 40),
    (300, 550, 137),
    ]


for i in range(len(data)):
    variable = len(data[i])
    if variable == 3:
        for num1, num2, num3 in data[i]:
            if num1 < num2:
                if num1 < num3:
                    answer.insert(0, num1)
            if num2 < num1:
                if num2 < num3:
                   answer.insert(0, num1)
            else:
                answer.insert(0, num3)
```

print(answer)

I've tested to make sure that the integer from the for loop using len() gives the correct value. I've experimented with the data[i] variable in hopes that was the problem. The loop to find out the smallest number worked when I removed the single 3 tuple, but in larger scale data that won't be an option.

Thanks again!

Comment: Your second call to `answer.insert` is using `num1`, not `num2`, as an argument. It's not clear why you are using `answer.insert` instead of answer.append`.

Comment: `(3)` is not a tuple; `(3,)` is.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I haven't used min() yet and that makes this much easier! Thanks for clarifying better ways to access data[i] as well. This help clear up a lot of syntax for me. Oops, on not having a comma after my 3 to make it a tuple. I used insert, because i had the wrong variable before and thought append() wouldn't work on tuples, but now I better. Thanks for your time, I really do appreciate it!.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing an extra iteration here:

```
        for num1, num2, num3 in data[i]:
            if num1 < num2:
```

This will iterate over each element of `data[i]` and then try to destructure it as `num1, num2, num3` (which fails because `data[i]` is itself the 3-tuple you want, at least if I'm interpreting your description correctly -- it'd be helpful to see a sample value of `data`).

What I think you want to do instead is to just destructure `data[i]` itself into 3 elements rather than trying to destructure each of its elements into 3 more elements:

```
        num1, num2, num3 = data[i]
        if num1 < num2:
```

A simpler way to do the whole thing would be to use the `min` function in a list comprehension:

```
answer = [min(t) for t in data if len(t) == 3]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate your time. This is incredibly concise information and understandable. this was very helpful. I'm not cool enough yet to give you an upvote, but I appreciate the help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's simper to just try unpacking each tuple, catching the resulting `ValueError` if an exception is raised.

```
for t in data:
    try:
        num1, num2, num3  = t
    except ValueError:
        continue

    # Process num1, num2, and num3 to determine
    # which gets added to answer here.
    ...
```

Comment: I couldn't remember how to do ValueError off the top of my head when I was doing this, so i decided to be stubborn and try and make it work in my post. I'll keep this in my repertoire. Thanks for the help!